# Group Middle for one or two role is not working

Tags: laravel

i have 3 user Roles, SuperAdmin, Admin and User or guest, 3 groups of routes

> 1 = Assigning the roles to users (SuperAdmin).
>
> 2 = Admin Panel (SuperAdmin,Admin).
>
> 3 = index page (SuperAdmin,Admin,User or Guest).

these three group of routes is access by user with given permission. I tried many things but none of it works

> User Model

```
public function role(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role','role_assigns');
    }
 public function hasRole($role)
{
    if ($this->role()->where('name','=',$role)->first()){
        return true;
}return false;
}
public function isSuperAdmin() {
    return $this->role()->where('name', '=','superadmin')->exists();
}
public function isAdmin() {
    return $this->role()->where('name', '=','admin')->exists();
}
public function isUser() {
    return $this->role()->where('name', '=','user')->exists();
}
```

> Role Model

```
public function user(){
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role','role_assigns');
}
```

> Routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'roles:superadmin'], function (){
//    User Assiginign Routes
Route::get('/users', 'UserRoleController@showAllUser');
Route::get('/assign', 'UserRoleController@showRoleAndUser');
Route::post('/user/{user_id}    /role/{role_id}','UserRoleController@assignRoleToUser');
Route::post('assign_role/user/{user_id}/role/{role_id}',[
    'uses'=>'UserRoleController@assignRoleToUser',
    'as'=>'assign_role'
]);
Route::post('/ar', 'UserRoleController@showAllUser');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'roles:admin,superadmin'], function () {
//    Product Dashboard for Admin
Route::get('/', 'ProductController@index');
Route::post('add_product','ProductController@store');
Route::get('/edit/{id}','ProductController@edit');
Route::get('/delete/{id}','ProductController@destroy');
Route::post('/update_product/{id}','ProductController@update');
Route::get('/add_product', function () {
    return view('content.add_product');
});
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'roles:admin,superadmin,user'], function () {
Route::get('/index', 'ProductController@index_page')
});
```

> Middleware.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ... $roles)
{
   
    if (!Auth::check())
        return redirect('signin');

    $user = Auth::user();



    if ( $user->isSuperAdmin()) {
        return $next($request);
    }elseif ($user->isAdmin() ){
        return $next($request);
    }
    elseif ($user->isUser()||$request->user()->hasRole($roles)==null){
      return redirect('index');
    }       


   return response('Not Auttroize insufficent end of page',401);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply by getting all roles of a user and check if he has given permission:

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'roles:admin,superadmin,user'], function () {
        Route::get('/index', 'ProductController@index_page')
    });
```

Then in your Middleware you should do

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, string $roles)
    {
         $user_roles = Auth::user()->role;
         $roles = explode(',' $roles);
         if ($user_roles->whereIn('role', $roles)->count()) {
             return $next($request);
         }
         throw new Exeception('Unauthorized', 401)
    }
```

Comment: Does that work? `->whereIn()` is expecting an array as the second parameter, but you've got `string $roles`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-wherein

Comment: @TimLewis you corrcet , I fixed it

Comment: Error : Argument 3 passed to App\Http\Middleware\RoleCheckMiddleware::handle() must be of the type array, string given, 
Login email has role admin

Comment: @AliRaza It's impossible to get the same error if you changed the hint

Comment: edited code is giving error : Call to a member function whereIn() on null. `dd($roles)` return only admin, and `dd($user_roles)` return null

Comment: @AliRaza I miss typed your relation, it should be role, also, I don't know how your tables look like, please understand what I did and fit it to your needs

Comment: many to many relation, Role Model has 'name', i also change 'role' to 'name', and after change the relation, it is giving throw Exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194623/discussion-between-code-warrior-and-ali-raza).